# Confusion in using AlarmManager, intent while updating widget

Tags: android, performance, android-intent, android-widget, alarmmanager

I am new to Android development and Java and am trying to update my widget using AlarmManager but I am not able to fully understand why most of the tutorials do not update widgets in the following way. I am using textview to display a number in my widget and increment it once every second and decrement it by 10 when a widget is removed and reset to 0 when all widgets are removed.

```
public class widget_1_1 extends AppWidgetProvider {
    private static int var1 = 0;

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        AppWidgetManager widgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
        ComponentName widgetComponent = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(), this.getClass().getName());
        int[] widgetId = widgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(widgetComponent);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        if (intent.getAction().equals(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE))
        {
            this.onUpdate(context, AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context), widgetId);
            alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()+1000, 1000, pendingIntent);
        }
        else if (intent.getAction().equals(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_DELETED))
        {
            // one widget deleted
            var1-=10;
        }
        else if (intent.getAction().equals(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_DISABLED))
        {
            // last widget deleted
            alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
            var1=0;
        }
    }

    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds)
    {
         var1++;
        // Code to update widget by calling appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget here
    }
}
```

Is there something wrong with this method above? All the tutorials I see use a private static final String alarmAction = "com.elison.widget1.ALARM_ACTION" or similar string in the class and use it to get PendingIntent. I do not understand what is its benefit and why not the above simple method?

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
    // Some code
    Intent enable = new Intent(alarmAction);
    intent.setClass(context, WYDAppWidgetProvider_4_1.class);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, enable, 0);
    // Some tutorials use PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT instead of 0 in 4th parameter
    // more code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only problem with your code is that `PendingIntent` creation should be inside if statement which checks whether its WIDGET_UPDATE action or not. And other thing is that you don't need to create `AlarmManager` every time as you are using repeating alarm manager. Also you extracting `widgetId` array manually every time, it should also be in if statement.